# issue with RegistryKey when using opensubkey and then changing that subkey

Tags: c#

OK, so i'm having this issue and i really just dont understand why. although i know i can just change the whole text i would just like to better understand why this is happening. so lets say im opening a subkey

```
RegistryKey regkey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, workstation, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(@"Software\Censored\Issuance\test\", true);
```

that will work fine i can set/get key values and such but then lets say i need to move to another subkey why cant i just do

```
regkey= regkey.opensubkey(@"\Software\something\somewhere\youknow");
```

then start setting or getting values from that new location? any help would be appreciated!

i tried to search for a similar post but didnt appear that anyone had asked about this before sorry if it's a dupe!

Comment: Are you missing the second parameter to enable editing on this regkey?

Comment: yes, but this was an example i couldnt even read the registry value with that

Comment: honestly you cant even read the regkey.getkeynames() from that lol it seriously just returns null is if whatever path you are using doesnt exist, although it does because if i reset it, using `regkey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, workstation, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(@"Software\somewhere\someplace\youknow\", true);`
it will then work again. drives me nuts lol

Comment: `\Software\something\somewhere\youknow` is (presumably) not a *subkey* of `\Software\Censored\Issuance\test` - its a path from the root. Store the `RegistryKey` from `OpenRemoteBaseKey` and call it on that.

Comment: this issue has nothing to do with the actual path, unless after you set opensubkey anything there after that's used tries to move one step farther, and if that is the case how does one reset it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RegistryKey regkey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, workstation, RegistryView.Registry64)
                     .OpenSubKey(@"Software\Censored\Issuance\test\", true);

regkey = regkey.opensubkey(@"Foo");
```

This will open the **subkey** `Foo` at `Software\Censored\Issuance\test\Foo`

To read from a key that is not a *subkey*

```
RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, workstation, RegistryView.Registry64);

RegistryKey regkey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Censored\Issuance\test\", true);
            ...
            regkey = baseKey.OpenSubKey(@"Software\something\somewhere\youknow", true);
```

Comment: as long as i stay in HKLM as defined in the openremotebasekey i believe that `@"\software\wherever"` would be a "subkey" of that, so this still doesnt answer my question of WHY, WHY wont it allow me to switch the subkey without having to define two different objects as registry keys when i dont need to?

Comment: But your not in HKLM as your `regkey` has explicitly opened `Software\Censored\Issuance\test\"` - you "go past" `OpenRemoteBaseKey` and chain on a call to `OpenSubKey`

Comment: I suppose that once you open a key, that key becomes as a 'root' of your registry view. You can open subkeys of that key but you cannot go back to the original root and choose a different path.

Comment: i think you hit the nail on the head steve... which is annoying because it requires another line of code. ohh well. thanks guys